# database having only one table with one column and one value size > over 200mb

Tags: sqlite

I have been playing with database, I imported over million columns, played with functions at the end i selected only one value, deleted the rest of it and my database is the size over 200mb. I am doing it in sqlite3. How to reduce the size of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is probably still reserving the space from your previous records.

This is essentially the same question:

[Why does clearing an SQLite database not reduce its size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544827/why-does-clearing-an-sqlite-database-not-reduce-its-size)

The accepted answer:

When an object (table, index, trigger, or view) is dropped from the database, it leaves behind empty space. This empty space will be reused the next time new information is added to the database. But in the meantime, the database file might be larger than strictly necessary. Also, frequent inserts, updates, and deletes can cause the information in the database to become fragmented - scrattered out all across the database file rather than clustered together in one place.

The VACUUM command cleans the main database by copying its contents to a temporary database file and reloading the original database file from the copy. This eliminates free pages, aligns table data to be contiguous, and otherwise cleans up the database file structure.

Edit: you may want to research the pragma command 'auto_vacuum' if you expect to be doing this regularly. It will keep your file size down but has some pros and cons. In a production environment It is best to reserve more space than you need, as this reduces the risk of running out of disk space on the server.